# Add a plugin to an installed eclipse rcp software without modifying config.ini

Tags: eclipse, plugins, config, rpc

I have an installed eclipse RPC application and I want to add a plugin to it which I just wrote. To acheive this I copied the new plugin into the plugin folder of my application and added the plugin to the list of plugins in the `config.ini` file found under `\configuration\config.ini`.

This works, but I don't like messing around with the config file. Is there a way to get new plugins working without adding them to the list or do I have to do this for every single plugin I create?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export is as a plugin and put the resulting jar files inside the dropins folder of your Eclipse RCP?

Comment: I seem to be missing such a folder. In my root directory I have the following folders: configuration, export, plugins, projects and workspace.